# How can I implement dynamic variables into my GET API requests using postgREST and python?

Tags: python, postgresql, get, postgrest

I'm building an API using PostgREST... I'm confused on how-to replicate the query below, more specifically, utilizing the parameters inputted by users =  `%s`.

```
SELECT symbol, date, adj_close 
FROM api.security_price 
WHERE security_price.symbol IN %s AND date 
> (SELECT MAX(date) FROM api.security_price) - interval '1 years' 
ORDER by date;
```

In python, it looks something like this = `get_data_from_db("SELECT symbol, date, adj_close FROM api.security_price WHERE security_price.symbol IN %s AND date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM api.security_price) - interval '1 years' ORDER by date;", [placeholders])`

Where I pass placeholders, the second argument, which holds the value(s) inputted by the user.

How would I be able to accomplish user-generated `GET` requests using an enviroment variable like `placeholders` to create the exact same examples above?.

here is the [postgREST documentation](https://postgrest.org/en/v0.4/api.html), postgres autogenerates api schema based on table/column names, pretty straightforward. However they don't mention case-scenarios like mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view, like:

```
create view foo as 
  select 
    symbol, 
    date, 
    adj_close
  from api.security_price 
  where 
    date > (select max(date) from api.security_price) - interval '1 years' 
  order by 
    date;
```

Use an HTTP request like:

```
GET /foo?symbol=in.(APPL,GOOG)
```